# Unable to check the item selected in MaterialSpinner

Tags: android, spinner

I am using the Material Spinner library in an activity. I am unable to check the option/item selected by the user in the material spinner.

https://github.com/jaredrummler/MaterialSpinner

I followed the instructions given in the above GitHub link

I think my problem is similar to this. https://github.com/jaredrummler/MaterialSpinner/issues/36

```
public class ChooseStateRoleName extends AppCompatActivity {

List<Agm_Data> agm_data = new ArrayList<>();

MaterialSpinner stateSpinner, roleSpinner, nameSpinner;
Button nextButton;
private int selectedState;
private int selectedRole;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_state_role_name);

    String[] STATES = {"Karnataka", "Andra Pradesh","Tamil Nadu", "Kerala", "Goa", "Maharastra", "Gujarat", "Orissa", "Madhya Pradesh", "Rajastan", "Jharkand", "Bihar", "Uttar Pradesh", "West Bengal", "Haryana", "Punjab", "Assam", "Meghalaya", "Tripura"};
    String[] ROLES = {"AGM", "TGE", "DP"};

    final ArrayAdapter<String> stateAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, STATES);
    ArrayAdapter<String> roleAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, ROLES);

    stateAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    roleAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    stateSpinner = (MaterialSpinner) findViewById(R.id.select_state_spinner);
    roleSpinner = (MaterialSpinner) findViewById(R.id.select_role_spinner);
    nameSpinner = (MaterialSpinner) findViewById(R.id.select_name_spinner);
    nextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
    stateSpinner.setAdapter(stateAdapter);
    roleSpinner.setAdapter(roleAdapter);

    stateSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MaterialSpinner.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(MaterialSpinner view, int position, long id, Object item) {
            selectedState = view.getSelectedIndex();
            Log.v("Selected state: ", String.valueOf(selectedState));
    });
}
```

As soon as I select an item in the spinner, I see the logcat as shown below.
logcat:

```
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4

W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.

W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
```

Comment: Experiencing the same thing. Did you ever figure out what was going on here?

Comment: This was one year ago, I don't remember what I did.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways:

1. Try this one:

```
selectedState = String.valueOf(stateSpinner.getSelectedIndex());
```

This will give you an int, which you can use very easily.

2. Or this one, whitch will give you String with some white spaces in the front:

```
selectedState = item;
```